# What is an index for how well IE 9 supports HTML5 and CSS3? Is Acid3 test score a good index?

Tags: html, css, acid3

I thought the Acid3 test score of 95 for IE 9 might be a good index for seeing how well it supports HTML5 and CSS3, but then later found out that Acid3's Wiki has little mentioning of HTML5 and CSS3: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid3

Is Acid3 score a good indicator for HTML5 and CSS3 support?  If not, is there a score that gives a good index for them?

Answer (score 2):

Acid3 doesn't tell you anything.
Use http://caniuse.com/ to see which technologies are available in browsers.

Comment: but is there an index or score?

Answer (score 1):

[The HTML5 test - How well does your browser support HTML5](http://www.html5test.com/)

**or**

[Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) is an open source, MIT-licensed JavaScript library that detects support for many HTML5 & CSS3 features.

Comment: nice.  know any one for CSS 3?